# Cannot get ngrok to serve up my WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, tunneling, ngrok

I have a simple wordpress install using Mamp Free Version on OS/X.

> Version                       2.0.19/2.0.19
>   Web Interface                 h#tp#//127.0.0.1:4040
>   Forwarding                    h#tp#//6c219c8e.ngrok.io ->
>   localhost:8888                                Forwarding
>   h#tps#//6c219c8e.ngrok.io -> localhost:8888
>   Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50
>   p90
>                                 1       0       0.00    0.00    6.00    6.00

For some reason when I try the links generated by ngrok, the website loads forever, then I get

> Page not available.

Comment: make sure you website is running at localhost:8888 and firewall is not blocking that port.

Comment: I checked, I don't have a firewall running on my laptop, and I checked the port to confirm it was 8888 in MAMP.

Answer (score 10):

As @Magico stated, download from the repo https://github.com/jonathanbardo/WP-Ngrok-Local and place that in your plugins directory, activate the plugin.

Then, after you get your ngrok tunnel URL up & running, take that URL and place it in your `wp-config.php` as follows:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.ngrok.io/' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.ngrok.io/' );
```

Now you will be able to access the homepage **as well as** the admin dashboard.

Comment: Doing this actually results in a redirection loop and apparently doesn´t work for me.

Comment: Instructions are here https://ngrok.com/docs#wordpress  Need to use relative URLs.

Comment: Updated link to instructions here: https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with#wordpress

Answer (score 6):

According to the [faq](https://ngrok.com/faq#wordpress):

> You need to add one of the following plugins to force Wordpress to issue relative URLs.
>
> - https://github.com/optimizamx/odt-relative-urls

Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to post the rest of links.

Answer (score 4):

You can start ngrock setting your virtual host and your port with this command:

```
ngrok http -host-header=dev.yoursite 8080
```

and then install and activate only **one** of these plugin to navigate with relative urls

https://github.com/jonathanbardo/WP-Ngrok-Local (i'm using this one)

https://github.com/optimizamx/odt-relative-urls

http://wordpress.org/plugins/relative-url/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/root-relative-urls/

full article and documentation here 
https://ngrok.com/faq#virtual-hosts

Answer (score 1):

I'm not having luck with this approach. I'm using a plugin called "Relative URL" but only the homepage is rendering on my end. Other pages in the site do not show up. The site is running locally as localhost:8888 which is the path I set temporarily in the SETTINGS>GENERAL SETTINGS and I noticed with the Relative URL plugin running it's still trying to throw the :8888 on the end of the ngrok URL. Just don't know what to do about it currently.

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 1):

The Relative URL plugin in wordpress got my site loading correctly remotely through ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is still having an issue with ngrok on wordpress , you can follow these steps:

1. After running ngrok copy the link and edit siteurl and home column in wp_options table
2. Go on administration panel and then edit your menus by adding ngrok_url generated.